# ESC wiring to FC for wing - 2 or 3 pins?

Tags: esc, fixed-wing, telemetry

I'm new to the wing builds and I'm a bit confused. I ordered [the kit](https://www.banggood.com/de/Sonicmodell-AR-Wing-Pro-Power-Combo-2216-KV1400-Brushless-Motor-and-40A-ESC-w-or-5V-3A-BEC-and-9g-Metal-Gear-Servo-and-8050-8x5-2-Blade-Propeller-p-1757615.html) for the AR Wing Pro, which includes BLDC motor and ESC. The ESC comes with the mandatory 2 power lines and 3 thick lines for the motor. Also it provides the common 3 pin servo plug and a additional two wire plug that looks like a low voltage DC output to me
[image]

On the other side my flight controller [H743-WLITE manual](https://www.mateksys.com/downloads/Manual/H743-WLITE_Manual.pdf) notes, that you should not connect all 3 pins of the servo connector, as it would provide also power back to the FC and cause damage?
[image]

Now I'm confused what needs to be connected to get DSHOT150 with telemetry for INAV? Is the middle red wire a power or TX?
Would love to get some tipps from more experienced pilots :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that model and couldn't find any instructions for the ESC, but plugs like that are usually used for power. It's very unusual to have two sets of battery plugs on an ESC like this.

I guess it's there in case you want to use it to power the VTX and camera. Note that the ESC may not have been designed specifically for this model, and there's some variation in the voltages used by various VTXs and cameras. One of the challenges of fixed wing FPV is that you often don't need a power distribution board for the motor, so finding somewhere to power the FPV gear involves modifying the ESC, or soldering extra wires to the battery plug.

You could use a voltmeter to see if it's 5v from the BEC or battery voltage. It could even be a 9 or 12v output.

If you don't have a voltmeter, you could open the heat shrink on the ESC slightly to see if it's just connected to the battery wires.

Just because it's there doesn't mean you have to use it, but it may make connecting the FPV gear easier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation! I have only experience with FC, where you usually have not a power problem, as BEC or PDB is mixed in. Following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPktdBh2Gcw) I learned that telemetry doesn't work easily on every ESC (here: anything supporting BLheli32 fw), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlQplDPdIQ4) explains why it's usually somewhat useless with a FC ;-)